# I would like a mysql query. All the fields which contain a capital letter

Tags: mysql

I have a little trouble with this query and google is not my friend today

I all the results of a table that contains one or more capital letters. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM personal_urls WHERE CONTAINS_UPCASE(vanity_url)
```

Somebody knows an easy solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
        SELECT * 
        FROM personal_urls 
        WHERE CAST(vanity_url  AS BINARY) RLIKE '[A-Z]';
```

Comment: That returns everything which contains [A-Za-z]. For some reason the regexp isnt case sensitive by default. With REGEXP BINARY it does work. Thanks anyways!

Comment: The regexp isn't case sensitive because you're using a case insensitive collation

Answer (score 3):

I think RLIKE string function can help. We may use regexp [A-Z] to test string for capital letters.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself.

```
SELECT * FROM personal_urls WHERE vanity_url REGEXP BINARY '[A-Z]'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may like to try

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`columnName`) FROM personal_urls WHERE `columnName` LIKE BINARY Upper(`columnName`)
```

Comment: I tested this and it only gives results for completely uppercased fields. But i needed  which contains one or more uppercased.

Comment: @Michael: Right. I updated your question for (one or more) capital letters.

Comment: @Miachel: RLIKE BINARY will give similar results to REGEXP BINARY

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I ran across it today so I'll leave this here for anyone coming from Google.

You can just compare each record to the lowercase version of itself. The only subtlety is that regular string comparison isn't case sensitive if you're using a case-insensitive collations (which you probably are if you're asking this question). Comparing values as binary with the `BINARY` keyword will force case sensitivity.

```
SELECT * FROM personal_urls WHERE vanity_urls != BINARY LOWER(vanity_urls)
```